# Can a prebaked cheesecake be baked again inside a cake batter

Tags: cake, cheesecake

I want to attempt to make a Christmas Piecaken. One of the layers I want to put a 7” cheesecake inside a 10” springform pan and pour red velvet cake batter around it.  Will the cheesecake hold up being baked again like this?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's much "conventional wisdom" in the area of baking one thing into the center of another. Though, the "original" Piecaken from Zac Young is actually just separate items stacked together, rather than being baked into each other.

Comment: I have no experience, but I’m going to assume that you’ll want to bake the cake at a higher than typical temperature, so the cake sets on the outside before the heat fully penetrates to the middle.  At least if the cheesecake is perfectly centered…. Which would be difficult, because it’s going to fall to the bottom of the cake tin.  If it were me, I’d bake a separate bottom, and bake the ‘filled’ cake inside a larger cake tin with some sort of spacer and a thin layer of water to insulate the bottom